# Is there a limit to file size upload on Ollama Web UI

Tags: ollama

I am using Ollama Web Ui with dolphin mistral. I am using this to summarize files. But I want the model to know some context(kinda like a RAG based system). For that I want to uplaod a large .txt file (55MB) and i get this,

````
Something went wrong :/
Error loading /app/backend/data/uploads/output.txt```



Has anyone else faced this issue? Is this because of file size. How do I work my way around this?
````